# Custom rule not recognized by ESLint

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint

I need to write a custom rule for ESLint to check if someone uses certain code constructs. I am new to ESLint and am having some problems registering the rule so I can actually use it in the `.eslintrc` configuration file. The rule itself looks as follows:

**some-custom-rule.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(context) {

  function applyRule(node) {
    // some logic
  }

  return {
    "Identifier": applyRule
  }
};

module.exports.schema = [];
```

Then I have the following configuration file:

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "blockBindings": true,
    "forOf": true,
    "modules": true,
    "arrowFunctions": true,
    "classes": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": 2,
    "some-custom-rule": 2
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  }
}
```

When I try to execute ESLint with a Gulp task, the following errors pops up: `1:1  error  Definition for rule 'some-custom-rule' was not found`. I assume this is because I didn't require the rule properly.

The Gulp task is as follows:

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var conf = require('./conf');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var rule = require('./rules/some-custom-rule');

gulp.task('eslint', function () {
  return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '**/*.js'))
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

How can I make use of my custom rule? Do I have to pass it to ESLint or something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is the info: http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two ways to register rules with ESLint, you can use `--rulesdir` command-line flag and pass it a directory where your custom rules are located. If you do that, all of the rules in that directory will be automatically registered with ESLint. This way, however, is deprecated. A better way would be to create a `plugin`, which is a way to distribute bundle of rules through NPM module. You can find more information about creating a plugin [here](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins).